# Applying colocalization analysis in Asian populations

Tags: gwas, software-usage, meta-analysis, gtex, qtls

I am planning to add colocalization method as a post-GWAS analysis in my study which is solely based on east Asian populations. I have noticed that **coloc**, **enloc** and **eCaviar** are being commonly used for colocalization analysis but all of which are being conducted in European GWAS or European dominant meta-analyses. Some stated that GTEx eQTL data, which might be a part of requirements in these tools, was mainly generated from European populations, and thus, it would be difficult to get the accurate results in Asian populations because of LD differences. So, if anybody who had similar experiences or who did colocalization methods in Asian GWAS is here, please let me know how to deal with this.